# How to disable the navigation bar slide animation when going fullscreen?

Tags: android, animation, transition

I have an activity that goes to another full screen activity. However, when transitioning from this activity to my full screen activity, the navigation bar slides down instead of disappearing instantly. I've inflated a full-screen window in the second activity, but because of the slow sliding animation, it resizes 1 second later after the animation has completed instead of being inflated to full-screen immediately. Therefore, I need the animation to disappear instantly. I've tried

`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>`

and

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

and

```
Transition fade = new Fade();
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
```

with no luck.

On the Windows side, I've tried

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
```

How I hide the navbar: `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think, I nailed it:

[image]

`FullscreenActivity` class:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"/>
```

Styles:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

**NB!** Setting `StatusBar` colour required **API 21**. **For the older versions**, to "hide" StatusBar, you need use:

```
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
```

as uiOptions in the code above. (it'll cause quite quick resizing, though).

I hope, it helps